# Inner if statement is skipped for some reason during debug and run

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, nested-if

The inner if statement is being skipped completely, when I step through the code It never enters updateGrade. It just skips the if entirely. why?

heres the method in question:

```
public void updateCourse(String courseID, String newLetterGrade){

    for(int i=0; i<classesTaken.size(); i++){

        if(classesTaken.contains(courseID)){
        classesTaken.get(i).updateGrade(newLetterGrade);
        }
    }
}
```

according to my debugger when i = 5 and my arrayList = 6 once i hits 6 it passes breaks out of the loop right away for no reason. I'm not sure what is wrong as there are no errors shown at make or when running.

this is the method that is called when contents of courseID is found in classesTaken:

```
public void updateGrade(String newGrade){
    letterGrade=newGrade;
    compute(newGrade);
```

My test file looks like this:

```
public class TranscriptTester {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Transcript test = new Transcript("11234", "Cody");
    test.addCourse("COP2013","A+");
    test.addCourse("COP2014","B+");
    test.addCourse("COP2015","B+");
    test.addCourse("COP2016","D+");
    test.addCourse("COP2017","A");
    test.addCourse();
    test.updateCourse("COP2013", "B-");
    test.updateCourse("COP2014", "A+");
    test.getGPA();
    test.printArray();
    test.toString();
}
}
```

according to my code it should jump into the if statement at the first iteration of classesTaken because COP2013 is at 0 index.

If you need anymore information in order to help me just ask. Thanks!

here is all of the class files if you want to see what all of it is:

```
public class Course {

//global variables
private String courseID;
private String letterGrade;
private Double numberGrade;

//CONSTRUCTORS
//param
public Course(String id, String letter){
courseID = id;
letterGrade=letter;
compute(letter);
}
//default
public Course(){
    courseID = "COP2053";
    numberGrade = 4.0;
    letterGrade = "A";
    compute(getLetterGrade());
}


//COMPUTING GRADES AND UPDATING
private void compute(String letter){


    if(letter == "A+"){numberGrade = 4.0;}
    else if(letter == "A"){numberGrade = 3.67;}
    else if(letter == "A-"){numberGrade = 3.33;}
    else if(letter == "B+"){numberGrade = 3.00;}
    else if(letter == "B"){numberGrade = 2.67;}
    else if(letter == "B-"){numberGrade = 2.33;}
    else if(letter == "C+"){numberGrade = 2.00;}
    else if(letter == "C"){numberGrade = 1.67;}
    else if(letter == "C-"){numberGrade = 1.33;}
    else if(letter == "D+"){numberGrade = 1.0;}
    else if(letter == "D"){numberGrade = .67;}
    else if(letter == "D-"){numberGrade = .33;}
    else if(letter == "F"){numberGrade = 0.0;}

}

public void updateGrade(String newGrade){
    letterGrade=newGrade;
    compute(newGrade);
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "\nCourse: "+getCourseID()+"\nLetter Grade: "+getLetterGrade()
          +"\nGPA in course: "+numberGrade;

}




//GETTERS
public String getCourseID(){
    return courseID;
}

public String getLetterGrade(){
    return letterGrade;
}

public Double getNumberGrade(){
    return numberGrade;
}



}
```

Transcript file:

```
public class Transcript {

private ArrayList<Course> classesTaken = new ArrayList<Course>();

public Transcript(String studentID, String studentName){
     System.out.println("\nStudent ID: "+studentID+"\nStudent Name: "+studentName);
}

public void addCourse(String courseID, String letterGrade){
    Course myCourse = new Course(courseID,letterGrade);
    classesTaken.add(myCourse);
}

public void addCourse(){
    Course myCourse = new Course();
    classesTaken.add(myCourse);
}

public void updateCourse(String courseID, String newLetterGrade){

    for(int i= 0; i<classesTaken.size(); i++){

        if(classesTaken.get(i).equals(courseID)){
        classesTaken.get(i).updateGrade(newLetterGrade);
        }
    }
}

public void getGPA(){
    System.out.println("\nOverall GPA: "+calculateGPA());
}

private Double calculateGPA(){
    Double overallGPA = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<classesTaken.size(); i++){
    overallGPA = classesTaken.get(i).getNumberGrade()+overallGPA;
    }

    return overallGPA / classesTaken.size();
}

public void printArray(){
    for(int i=0; i<classesTaken.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("\n"+classesTaken.get(i));
    }
}



}
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us what "Transcript" and "classesTaken" are.

Comment: I'm also curious as to what classesTaken.contains() is supposed to do. You're calling it inside your loop but it doesn't take "i" as an argument, so why not call it outside the loop?  Or did you mean classesTaken.get(i).contains()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at your code I see that you're misusing (unless you use `equals` with `String`) the `contains` method:

```
classesTaken.get(i).updateGrade
```

You're invoking `updateGrade` on object (of some type, not `String`), which is obviously not `String` type.

But you try to find the `String` in the list `classesTaken` list:

```
classesTaken.contains(courseID)
```

Obviously there are no `String`'s in this list. Otherwise the code wouldn't even compile (because `String` hasn't `updateGrade` method)

You should override `equals` or provide other method for finding out if the string is in the collection of object of your custom class

You should do something like this (let assume your class is `ClassTaken`):

```
for(int i=0; i<classesTaken.size(); i++){
    ClassTaken c = classesTaken.get(i);
    if(c.getCourseId().equals(courseID)){
        c.updateGrade(newLetterGrade);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your updateCourse method, you are comparing a Course object (an item from classesTaken ArrayList) with a String object (courseID). So the if condition is never satisfied.

Like the following, override the equals method in the Course class so that you could use the "contains" method to compare courses.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof Course))return false;
    Course otherCourse = (Course)other;
    return this.courseID.equals(otherCourse.courseID);
}
```

And then you need to update the updateCourse method in your Transcript class as well to make sure objects of the same type are being compared:

```
public void updateCourse(String courseID, String newLetterGrade){   
    Course c = new Course(courseID, newLetterGrade);    
    for(int i= 0; i<classesTaken.size(); i++){
        if(classesTaken.get(i).equals(c)){
            classesTaken.get(i).updateGrade(newLetterGrade);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful; you can't use "==" to compare strings

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was going for but it does give me some ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `classesTaken` stores Courses, not Strings. So it will never contain the ID itself.

It seems like what you might want is something along the lines of `classesTaken.get(i).getID().equals(courseID)`, assuming a `getID` function.